# Ant Condition task

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I have not been able to find the answer to this question and, as you will see, it is not important in understanding how the build.xml I am trying to reverse engineer works. Nevertheless I do think that the question has some validity.

In this build.xml I have the following segment of code:

```
<condition property="tests.complete">
    <isset property="no.tests" />
</condition>
<condition property="tests.complete">
    <and>
        <uptodate>
            ...
        </uptodate>
        <uptodate>
            ...
        </uptodate>
        <uptodate>
            ...
        </uptodate>
        <not>
            <available ... />
        </not>
        <not>
            <isset ... />
        </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

I do understand that if the property no.tests is set before this segment of code is encountered then the property tests.complete will be set to true in the first condition and no matter what happens in the second condition task, this property will remain set to true on leaving the code segment. My question is, given that the property tests.complete is set by the first condition do the second set of condition tests get evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Only clean (not defined) properties can be set. If your property is already set, nothing is done.

So, no, the second set of conditions are not evaluated. You can test it using this code:

```
<target name="run">
    <property name="no.tests" value="true"/>
    <condition property="tests.complete">
        <isset property="no.tests" />
    </condition>
    <echo message="${tests.complete}"/> <!-- prints true -->

    <condition property="tests.complete" else="false">
        <isset property="whatever" /> <!-- property whatever is not set -->
    </condition>
    <echo message="${tests.complete}"/> <!-- prints true as well! -->
</target>
```

You can test it too using the opposite:

```
<target name="run">
    <property name="whatever" value="true"/>
    <condition property="tests.complete" else="false">
        <isset property="no.tests" /> <!-- no.tests isn't defined -->
    </condition>
    <echo message="${tests.complete}"/> <!-- prints false -->

    <condition property="tests.complete" else="false">
        <isset property="whatever" /> <!-- the property whatever is defined -->
    </condition>
    <echo message="${tests.complete}"/> <!-- prints false as well! -->
</target>
```